# linker error on compile separate .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, makefile

What is the correct way to compile this?
minimum code to demonstrate the problem:

```
//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto z = myNameSpace::Complex(1, 2);
    cout << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
////////////////////////////////////////
//header.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
namespace myNameSpace
{
class Complex
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Complex(int x, int y);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &a);
};
}
///////////////////////////////////
//header.cpp
#include "header.h"
using myNameSpace::Complex;
Complex::Complex(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &a)
{
    os << a.x << "+i" << a.y;
    return os;
}
```

I want to use make to compile separate objects and link them what am I missing?
here is the output of my make command

```
$ make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o header.o header.cpp
g++ -o main.exe main.o header.o
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `myNameSpace::operator<<(std::ostream&, myNameSpace::Complex const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: main.exe] Error 1
```

and this is my make file

```
main.exe: main.o header.o
    g++ -o main.exe main.o header.o

header.o: header.cpp header.h

main.o: main.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o
```

Comment: How does your `Makefile` look like?

Comment: I think that the problem is your definition of operator<< is not in the correct namespace.

Comment: @NutCracker Updated the question with makefile

Answer (score 2):

I would write header.cpp like this

```
///////////////////////////////////
//header.cpp
#include "header.h"

namespace myNameSpace {

Complex::Complex(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &a)
{
    os << a.x << "+i" << a.y;
    return os;
}

}
```

Having `namespace myNameSpace { ... }` instead of `using myNameSpace ...` is the simplest way to get things right.

Comment: But I read somewhere that this method in not a good practice for some reason that the article did not mention!

Comment: @AminGholizad I don't know of any reason its bad practise. I would ignore that until the reason can be explained. Then make a decision when you know what the argument is.

Comment: @AminGholizad "this method" is just how namespaces are used. There is nothing bad about it. Fwiw, `using namespace std;`is really [considered bad practice](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/). At least you dont have it in the header where it can do more harm

Comment: Ok. But how about the Complex class is a template class. Then the problem still exists

Comment: Based on no code it's hard to know what the problem is, but template friends are tricky, see here https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html

Comment: And of course template code should go in header files, otherwise you do get linker issues